# JSP FORM POST : empty attributes

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I can't find one attribute sent from a JSP form.

```
<form name="shuntingForm" action="/TCS_FUND/ShuntAction.aen" method="POST">
                                            <div class="field-item clearfix">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="csrfPreventionSalt" value="<%=CsrfPreventionSalt%>" /> 
                                                <input type="hidden" name="idSession" value="<%=idSession%>"> 
                                                <a href="javascript:document.shuntingForm.submit();">Funds Trading</a><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

request.getAttribute("idSession") & request.getParameter("idSession") show NULL.

Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this to return a fixed value.

Change:
`<input type="hidden" name="idSession" value="<%=idSession%>">`

To:
`<input type="hidden" name="idSession" value="123456789">`

Once that works, figure out the difference.

You also may want to view the source of the web page. If your idSession does not have the value you expect, your input tag will show the wrong value field.